# How to associate a CUDA thread with a triple nested loop?

Tags: loops, cuda

Let's say that there are three variables `X`, `Y` and `Z` with minimum, maximum and variation step values, `minX`, `maxX`, `minY`, `maxY`, `minZ`, `maxZ` (the minimum and maximum values can have any value, negative or positive) and `stepX`, `stepY` and `stepZ`, respectively. Let us also define a function `W = f(X,Y,Z)` that gets these variables as arguments and returns a value `W`. Now, we want to estimate the value of `W` for all the possible combinations of `X`, `Y` and `Z` defined by the above parameters. Lets say that based on the above information we have estimated the number of iterations `xCircles`, `yCircles` and `zCircles` (from `minX`, `maxX`, `minY`, `maxY`, `minZ`, `maxZ`) of each one of the three loops in the associated nested structure. In this case, the serial version of this procedure is implemented as follows.

```
double curX, curY, curZ, W;
curX = minX; curY = minY; curZ = minZ;
for (long i=0;i<xCircles;i++) {
     for (long j=0;j<yCircles;j++) {
          curZ=minZ;
          for (long k=0;k<zCircles;k++) {
               W = f(curX,curY,curZ);
               curZ = minZ+(k+1)*stepZ;
               curY = minY+(j+1)*stepY; }
          curX = minX+(i+1)*stepX; }}
```

The objective is to parallelize this serial triple loop. The parallelization using OpenMP is very easy via `#pragma omp parallel` and the related directives and now I would like to do the same thing in CUDA. I suppose that the optimal kernel execution configuration regarding the number of threads per block and the number of blocks in grid as well as the associated dimensions is a matter of experimentation (even though some tips would be appreciated) and I work on the construction of the mapping between `threadIdx` and the coordinates `curX`, `curY` and `curZ` used in each iteration of the triple loop, namely a mapping in the form

```
(threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z) ---> (curX, curY, curZ)
```

In this way, we can assign to each thread the estimation of the value `f(threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z)` in order to remove completely the triple loop. Keep in mind that for large values of `minX`, `maxX`, `minY`, `maxY`, `minZ`, `maxZ` and small values of `stepX`, `stepY` and `stepZ`, the total number of function evaluations `xCircles` x `yCircles` x `zCircles`, may have a value of billions and it is reasonable to assume that each thread will perform not only one but a lot of computations whose number can be considered as a parameter of the problem.

Is there any idea regarding how to do this? Alternatively, does anyone know a book or a paper with such type of problems, to start reading?

In fact the problem has four different kinds of nested loops with depths d=1,2,3,4 but if I find a solution for this particular case (d=3), i will adapt it to the other cases.

Comment: What do you intend to do with W? Your sequential code makes no sense as W is just overwritten in the next iteration. If you write W to global memory, the exact mapping between coordinates and threads becomes much more important as you want to coalesce the global memory transactions.

Comment: Your sequential code is generally broken (I fixed the indentation to make it more obvious). There is also a `curY = minY;` missing inside the `i`-loop.

Comment: @paleonix: I just show a minimal code to describe the problem, but you have right: the way of treating W may affect the design. The function estimates the Lyapunov exponent of a chaotic time series created on the fly for a lot combinations of three parameters. When I estimate W for each combination, I check its value (the time series is chaotic if W>0 and nonchaotic if W<=0) and increment accordingly the values of two counters  (totalStates, chaoticStates). Later I will draw the chaotic regions using red colored for chaotic states and maybe store the results to files for offline processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a mapping in the form (threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z) ---> (curX, curY, curZ)

It seems trivial to compute curX, curY, curZ fron integer indices, here’s how:

```
double curX = fma( i, stepX, minX );
double curY = fma( j, stepY, minY );
double curZ = fma( k, stepZ, minZ );
```

If you want to test the above with CPU-running C++, `#include <cmath>` and `using std::fma;`

> total number of function evaluations xCircles x yCircles x zCircles, may have a value of billions

Yeah, spawning billions of CUDA threads can be suboptimal.

A typical workaround is spawning CUDA threads for each iteration of some outer loop, but write inner loop inside the CUDA kernel, i.e. write a `for` loop there.

For example, when xCircles=yCircles=zCircles=1000, you could launch a grid of 1000x1000 CUDA threads, and inside your kernel write the inner loop running 1000 iterations.

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris Yeah, but if you do just that, you gonna have billions of CUDA threads. These threads are cheap but not exactly free. The optimal count of them depends on GPU model and the code of your CUDA kernel, but ballpark estimate, often a good number of them is 10k-100k. Consider dispatching 2D grid of threads instead of 3D like I wrote in the second part. Use `threadIdx.x` and `threadIdx.y`, ignore `threadIdx.z`, and write the innermost loop inside the kernel.

Comment: Doing the FMA explicitly in the source code seems like premature optimization to me. The compiler is more than capable of doing this. Readability is better when just using `*` and `+` in my opinion.